# How to use Handler Postdelayed in queue?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, task-queue

I have a situation, I created a button and a function like this.

```
...
public void BtnOnClick(View view) {

    displayMsg();
}

...

private void displayMsg(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TestQueue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, 3000);

}
...
```

If I click the button once a Toast should appear after a 3 seconds delay.
But if I quickly click the button two or more times then all the Toasts appear at the same time after 3 seconds without delay of 3 seconds between every Toast it's not good. I want a 3 seconds gap/delay between every Toast appearance despite of simultaneous clicks.

Is there any solution?

**If there are multiple handlers in a queue then each handler delayed time start after the previous handler delay time end.**

Comment: What's your intension? Not to show new toast if one is already present or to queue toasts?

Comment: Toast is just for testing purpose i will use some other code here. I just want to queue my handler with delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can queue the requests to make sure the toasts are displayed at an interval.

```
ArrayList<Runnable> requests = new ArrayList<>;
bool inProgress = false;
private void displayMsg(){
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TestQueue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            inProgress = false;
            if (requests.size() > 0) {
                handler.postDelayed(requests.remove(0), 3000 + Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!inProgress) {
        inProgress = true;
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
    } else {
        requests.add(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: Not working all the toasts appear one by one without delay.

Comment: I am not sure how you are creating your class. You can try changing to `static ArrayList<Runnable> requests = new ArrayList<>;` But be careful, as this might cause a small memory leak if your activity is destroyed and you don't cleanup the list.

Comment: unfortunately nothing change

Comment: As I never added stuff to the queue, it didn't work... try now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

    final int DELAY = 3000;
    final int DELAY_MSG = 1;
    final Queue<Runnable> pendingRunnables = new ArrayDeque<>();

    @Override
    public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == DELAY_MSG) {
            final Runnable r = pendingRunnables.poll();
            if (r != null) {
                r.run();
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DELAY_MSG, DELAY);
            }
        } else {
            pendingRunnables.add(msg.getCallback());
            if (!hasMessages(DELAY_MSG)) {
                sendEmptyMessage(DELAY_MSG);
            }
        }
    }
};

...

// post action
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TestQueue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the best solution.

Comment: One more thing can you tell me how to change delay time for each Runnable?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`postAtTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)):

```
AtomicLong previous = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

private void displayMsg(){
    handler.postAtTime(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TestQueue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, previous.updateAndGet(operand -> Long.max(operand + 3000, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000)));
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: No, it requires API level 24 and i'm using minimum API 16